# Synaptics Touchpad unrecognized after Suspend in Ubuntu 14.04 on Dell Inspiron 11 3147

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad, suspend

I have nearly the same issue as [this other queston](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567754/touchpad-not-recognized-after-suspend-ubuntu-14-04-thinkpad-t420/572967#572967) on my Dell inspiron 11 3147, running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The touchpad works when I first login, if I logout and log back in it still works however when I close the screen and open it again then the touchpad is disabled  and the mouse is invisible.

The touchscreen and keyboard are unaffected.

The `modprobe -r psmouse` and then `modprobe psmouse` fix does not work, neither does solution 1 given [here](http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/fix-laptops-touchpadtrackpad-not.html) or the fix given [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2182922.html).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

When working (output shown below) after closing screen and opening again, the Synaptics Touchpad is no longer visible in the `xinput` list.

```
amp@ashesashesallfalldown:~$ xinput list 
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)] ⎜
↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎜ ↳ ELAN Touchscreen id=12 [slave pointer (2)] ⎜
↳ DLL064D:00 06CB:2985 id=13 [slave pointer (2)] ⎜
↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad id=15 [slave pointer (2)] 
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)] 
 ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)] 
 ↳ Video Bus id=7 [slave keyboard (3)] 
 ↳ Video Bus id=8 [slave keyboard (3)] 
 ↳ Power Button id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Sleep Button id=10 [slave keyboard (3)] 
 ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD id=11 [slave keyboard (3)] 
 ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard id=14 [slave keyboard (3)] 
 ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys id=16 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: See answer here. http://askubuntu.com/a/582553/185146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

Its is:

```
sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

then adding the line:

```
blacklist i2c_hid
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have a synaptics touchpad. Reloading the psmouse module won't help here.

try:

```
sudo modprobe -r i2c_hid && sudo modprobe i2c_hid
```

that might do the job.

Then you can adapt the solution from http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2182922.html , by replacing the appropriate kernel module and let it reload on wakeup.